# How to add shortcuts to modules in Nodejs Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

So we have a ReactTs project and we implemented shortcuts to things like our utils folder, So instead of calling the relative path everytime we use it in a module we just call @utils. We did this by adding path in our tsconfig.json.

This feature looks so handy and clean we decided to do the same on our Nodejs Typescript application. But when we compile the project and run the compliled js project it returns an error that seems @utils is not found. is there a way over this? How can we tell to compile the @utils to the declared relative path?

tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@interface": [
        "interface/index.ts"
      ],
    "@utils":[
        "src/utils/index.ts"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Project directory:[image]

Comment: Did you consult this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I implemented this npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias.